# What's the logic behind PERCENTILE.INC Excel function?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, percentile

I would like to know how does Excel think to calculate the values on the function PERCENTILE.INC. I'm making some studies on Percentile and Quartile, I got the below results:

[image: Percentile Example]

How does Excel think to calculate the values on column F?

Here's the formulas I'm using:

- =PERCENTILE.INC(B2:B21; 0,75) ==> F2
- =PERCENTILE.INC(B2:B21; 0,50) ==> F3
- =PERCENTILE.INC(B2:B21; 0,25) ==> F4
- =PERCENTILE.INC(B2:B21; 0,00) ==> F5

Comment: Does this help: https://www.statology.org/percentile-exc-vs-percentile-inc-excel/

Comment: I guess it's covered on the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile but I could post a specific answer to your question when time available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - the position of a given percentile when the data is sorted in ascending order, using percentile.inc, is given by

```
(N-1)p+1
```

where p is the required percentile as a fraction from 0 to 1 and N is the number of points.

If this expression gives a whole number, you take the value at this position (e.g. percentile zero gives 1, so its value is exactly 22). If it's not a whole number, you interpolate between the value at the position given by the whole number part (e.g. for p=0.25 it's 5 and the value at this position is 52) and the value at the position one higher (in this case position 6 so the number is 55), then multiply the difference of the two values (3) by the fraction part (0.75) giving you 2.25 and finally add this to the lower of the two values giving you 54.25. A shorter way of saying this is that you go a quarter of the way between the two nearest values. So you have:

[image]

If you wished to show the logic as an Excel formula, you could implement the expression shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) on the right (where *h*, in the second column of the table, is the position calculated from the formula above and *x* is the value at that position)

[image]

like this:

```
=LET(p,J3,
range,I$2:I$21,
N,COUNT(range),
position,(N-1)*p+1,
lower,FLOOR(position,1),
fraction,MOD(position,1),
upper,CEILING(position,1),
lowerValue,INDEX(range,lower),
upperValue,INDEX(range,upper),
difference,upperValue-lowerValue,
lowerValue+fraction*difference)
```

[image]